# Focus on Input after showing

Tags: jquery, html, animation, focus

I am trying to focus on an input after an animation slide into the screen.

```
$('.search-button').click(function() {
    $('#main-div').text('').hide()
    var m-s-s = $("#mSSIParentDiv");
    m-s-s.toggle('slide', { direction: 'right'}, 50);

    var main-input = $('#main-input');      
    if (main-input.length > 0) { main-input.focus(); }
});
```

This code fails to focus on the input once it slide out.

Am I missing any extra steps?

Comment: main-input.length is undefined

Comment: why not just do $('#main-input').focus() ?

Comment: The input loses focus when it fully expands. iT seems to be in focus for a split second

Comment: @DaveBriand - you realize that's exactly what he's doing ?

Comment: a variable name **CAN NOT** contain hyphens, it's interpreted as a minus sign.

Comment: ^ Fix that, and it should work -> **http://jsfiddle.net/buL9nhy7/**

Comment: @adeneo not with those minus signs as you pointed out. Plus it looks like he's making sure the input is there with the .length call, guessing that was during troubleshooting

Comment: After changing the name of the variables, I realised it only works with show() and not toggle('slide', { direction: 'right'}, 50);

Comment: For those trying to use toggle, try toggle('slide', { direction: 'right', complete: function(){$('#maininput').focus()}}, 50);

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking to float the items from the right saw ell as focus use the code below
    $(target)toggle('slide', { direction: 'right', complete: function(){$('#maininput').focus()}}, 50);